Upscale crab shacks in Baltimore
What does "crab shack" mean in "Today, this harbor area offers shops, upscale crab shacks and attractions like the Civil War–era warship the USS Constellation and the National Aquarium, showcasing thousands of marine creatures.?
I think it has to do with restaurants and seafood, but when I looked it up, I found this not-safe-for-work definition on UrbanDictionary.
Thank you for your help in advance!

The Urban Dictionary is not recommended as a reliable source of definitions.

UrbanDictionary is a site for slang definitions. While it's occasionally useful for understanding slang words, it's not going to give the "normal" definition. In this case, "crabs" is a slang term for pubic lice and "shack up with someone" is a slang phrase meaning moving in to live with a partner. And so there's a possible suggestive interpretation of crab shack (though I've never heard it used before). But for normal usage, a crab shack is a seafood restaurant.

It would be typical at a "crab shack" to have the crabs delivered to the table in the shell, along with wooden mallets to crack the shells. The "tablecloth" could even be newspapers.

"upscale" and "crab shack" is an oxymoron. It's like saying "a Michelin 4-star greasy spoon".

A crab shack is an eatery that serves seafood, typically in a casual setting (as you might expect from a 'shack') rather than a fancier restaurant environment. Adding "upscale" suggests it is fancier than you might expect a 'shack' to be.
This sort of definition is quite common. For example, here in Britain, the term 'gastro pub' was coined for pubs that serve restaurant-quality food as opposed to the usual 'pub fayre' which is traditionally more home-style cooking. There's quite a demand for traditional, home-style food but with a gourmet twist, and that's what I'd expect from an "upscale crab shack".
Regarding the link you found - "The Urban Dictionary" is a mainly humourous resource for slang words and phrases. A lot of the entries are highly offensive. The definitions there for 'crab shack' are crude double-entendres. Not what you were looking for.

It is also generally assumed that a crab shack gets its seafood from local fishermen, so what it's called depends on the dominant seafood catch in the area. You'll find crab shacks around Baltimore, but up in Maine, they're more likely to be lobster shacks and in Louisiana they're crawfish shacks. That's also how they can be "upscale" - they might have fancier food, but still focus on locally-caught seafood.

Near where I live there is a clam shack. It's like a seafood place and they sell from a window. Upscale suggests they have likka [haha] too. Maryland is especially known for its blue crabs and in Massachusetts there are no crab shacks. In Maryland, they might not sell that much other seafood and are only open during the crab season. (This is from memory I didn't look it up.)
